# Запись из массива в файл в bash

Tags: файлы, массивы, bash

Как записать значения из массива в файл в bash-е?

Answer (score 1):

`for i in "${arr[@]}"; do echo $i >> yourfile.txt; done`

Читайте документацию. Там, в принципе, ещё несколько десятков страниц.